# Recursive method call cause StackOverFlowError in kotlin but not in java

Tags: java, recursion, kotlin

I have two almost identical code in java and kotlin

***Java:***

```
public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    helper(s, 0, s.length - 1);
}

public void helper(char[] s, int left, int right) {
    if (left >= right) return;
    char tmp = s[left];
    s[left++] = s[right];
    s[right--] = tmp;
    helper(s, left, right);
}
```

***Kotlin:***

```
fun reverseString(s: CharArray): Unit {
    helper(0, s.lastIndex, s)
}

fun helper(i: Int, j: Int, s: CharArray) {
    if (i >= j) {
        return
    }
    val t = s[j]
    s[j] = s[i]
    s[i] = t
    helper(i + 1, j - 1, s)
}
```

The java code pass the test with a huge input but the kotlin code cause a `StackOverFlowError` unless i added `tailrec` keyword before the `helper` function in kotlin.

I want to know why this function works in java and also in kolin with `tailrec` but not in kotlin without `tailrec`?

**P.S:** 
i know what `tailrec` do

Comment: When I tested these, I found that the Java version would work for array sizes up to around 29500, but the Kotlin version would stop around 18500.  That's a significant difference, but not a very big one.  If you need this to work for big arrays, the only good solution is to use `tailrec`, or avoid recursion; the stack size available varies between runs, between JVMs and set-ups, and depending on the method and its params.  But if you're asking out of pure curiosity (a perfectly good reason!), then I'm not sure.  You'd probably need to look at the bytecode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know why this function works in **java** and also in **kotlin** with `tailrec` but not in **kotlin** without `tailrec`?

The short answer is because your **Kotlin** method is "heavier" than the **JAVA** one. At every call it calls another method that "provokes" `StackOverflowError`. So, see a more detailed explanation below.

**Java bytecode equivalents for `reverseString()`**

I checked the byte code for your methods in **Kotlin** and **JAVA** correspondingly:

*Kotlin method bytecode in JAVA*

```
...
public final void reverseString(@NotNull char[] s) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(s, "s");
    this.helper(0, ArraysKt.getLastIndex(s), s);
}

public final void helper(int i, int j, @NotNull char[] s) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(s, "s");
    if (i < j) {
        char t = s[j];
        s[j] = s[i];
        s[i] = t;
        this.helper(i + 1, j - 1, s);
    }
}
...
```

*JAVA method bytecode in JAVA*

```
...
public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    this.helper(s, 0, s.length - 1);
}

public void helper(char[] s, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        char temp = s[left];
        s[left++] = s[right];
        s[right--] = temp;
        this.helper(left, right, s);
    }
}
...
```

So, there're 2 main differences:

1. `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(s, "s")` is invoked for each `helper()` in the **Kotlin** version.
2. Left and right indices in **JAVA** method get incremented, while in **Kotlin** new indices are created for each recursive call.

So, let's test how `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(s, "s")` alone affects the behavior.

**Test both implementations**

I've created a simple test for both cases:

```
@Test
public void testJavaImplementation() {
    char[] chars = new char[20000];
    new Example().reverseString(chars);
}
```

And

```
@Test
fun testKotlinImplementation() {
    val chars = CharArray(20000)
    Example().reverseString(chars)
}
```

For **JAVA** the test succeeded without problems while for **Kotlin** it failed miserably due to a `StackOverflowError`. However, after I added `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(s, "s")` to the **JAVA** method it failed as well:

```
public void helper(char[] s, int left, int right) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(s, "s"); // add the same call here

    if (left >= right) return;
    char tmp = s[left];
    s[left] = s[right];
    s[right] = tmp;
    helper(s, left + 1, right - 1);
}
```

**Conclusion**

Your **Kotlin** method has a smaller recursion depth as it invokes `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(s, "s")` at every step and thus is heavier than its **JAVA** counterpart. If you don't want this auto-generated method then you can disable null checks during compilation as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360740/disable-not-null-checks-in-kotlin)

However, since you understand what benefit `tailrec` brings (converts your recursive call into an iterative one) you should use that one.

Comment: @user207421 every method invocation has its own stack frame including `Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(...)`. Obviously, each such stack frame requires a certain amount of memory (for the `LocalVariableTable` and operand stack and so on)..

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is just a tiny bit more stack hungry (Int object params i.o. int params). Besides the tailrec solution which fits here, you can eliminate the local variable `temp` by xor-ing:

```
fun helper(i: Int, j: Int, s: CharArray) {
    if (i >= j) {
        return
    }               // i: a          j: b
    s[j] ^= s[i]    //               j: a^b
    s[i] ^= s[j]    // i: a^a^b == b
    s[j] ^= s[i]    //               j: a^b^b == a
    helper(i + 1, j - 1, s)
}
```

Not entirely sure whether this works to remove a local variable.

Also eliminating j might do:

```
fun reverseString(s: CharArray): Unit {
    helper(0, s)
}

fun helper(i: Int, s: CharArray) {
    if (i >= s.lastIndex - i) {
        return
    }
    val t = s[s.lastIndex - i]
    s[s.lastIndex - i] = s[i]
    s[i] = t
    helper(i + 1, s)
}
```